# Using float to place an element in the right side with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a nav bar with a contact button stuck to the right of the page. I want contact to be aligned with the rest of the elements of the nav bar, however when I add `float: right;` it just disaligns my nav bar and it doesn't move contact to the right.

Here you can see my code: http://jsfiddle.net/LG2vR/19/

Can someone please tell me the proper way to accomplish this please?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need float right? I removed and it looks fine as you are expecting. http://jsfiddle.net/LG2vR/21/

Comment: Because I want the contact button to be on the right side of page

Comment: Did you check the fiddler I gave above? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yeah i checked it, no, I want the contact element to be right next to the right of the page like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LG2vR/33/     (but here I used a margin-left which changes it's position depending on the screen size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not sure if this is what you need exactly, see the updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ov74xcyg/1/
Basically, i have used position absolute to move your last child of the navigation to the right side and increased width of the navigation till the end of the header.

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  z-index: 500;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transition: .3s;
  background: red;
}

nav.white {
  background: white;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  transition: .5s;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
   position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  display: inline-block;
    right: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
  line-height: 80px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 12px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: .5s;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}


nav.white ul li a {
  color: #000;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: .5s;
}

nav ul li a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">LOGO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a class="contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
nav ul li a {
  float: left;
}
```

right before:

```
nav ul li a.contact {
  float: right;
}
```

or use `flexbox`!

Comment: But I want the contact button to be on the same level as the rest of the bar not the other way around

Comment: if you use flexbox, everything will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper li {list-style-type: none;}
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
.wrapper .logo{
  margin-right : 30px;
}
.wrapper a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.wrapper a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.wrapper a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="active logo" href="#">Logo</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Page 1</a>
  <a href="#">Page 2</a>
  <div class="topnav-right">
    <li><a class="contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
```